# Python block in a block

Tags: python, bash, sh

I'm trying to to read in the `ls -a` command in python,so the output would look like this one:
`[[.][..][DIR1][DIR2][FILE1]]`
the code so far is:

```
t=[]
import sh
lsa=sh.ls("-a")
for sor in lsa:
    t.append(sor)
print(t)
```

the output now is like this:

`['.  ..  FILE1  FILE2\n']`

(Sh is the module i use to execute bash commands)

Answer (score 4):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  The standard library function [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) produces the list you want (except that it does not include entries for `.` and `..` — but that *is* almost always the behavior you want) (also, you have to sort it yourself if you need it sorted).

```
>>> import os
>>> sorted(os.listdir("."))
['.ICE-unix', '.Test-unix', '.X0-lock', '.X11-unix', '.XIM-unix', ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

[zwol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153412/python-block-in-a-block/30153563#30153487) is right - you should use `os.listdir`.

To get the format you want you should use

```
print "[" + "".join("[{}]".format(file) for file in os.listdir('.')) + "]"
```

or

```
print "[[" + "][".join(os.listdir('.')) + "]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place the results in a list before you append them:

```
for sor in lsa:
    t.append(list(sor))
```

If your results are actually a single result which is a string, try:

```
lsa = lsa.split()
for sor in las:
    t.append(list(sor))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
from subprocess import check_output

a=check_output(["ls", "-a"])
print a.split()
```